# Not able display data in flat list after fetched data from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore

I have some data in my firestore. The structure is :

```
User -> DocId(Some id)-> name(String), number(String), friends (array)
```

I got the friends array and i append to my local array data. Now when i render in the flat list. Its not showing. But same temp data which i created locally its working fine. I check my array data count after i fetch from firestore. Its showing correct count. But not able to display the data in flat list.

**My code :**

```
  import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
    import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

    UserArray =[]

    export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {


 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            UserArray: [],
        }
      }
        componentWillMount() {

            firebase.firestore().doc(`User/${'beQVEcfLsXV8JhA8L2SDDq03bmD3'}`)
             .get()
             .then(doc => {
                this.setState({UserArray: doc.data().friends})
           })
         }

        renderPost = post => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.feedItem}>
                    <Feather  name="book" style={styles.avatar}  size={30}/>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.name}>{post.name}</Text>
                                  <Text style={styles.timestamp}>{post.name}  |  {post.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <Feather name="chevron-right" style={{color: "#808080", alignSelf: 'center'}} size={20}/>
                </View>
            );
        };

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {
                        UserArray.length ?
                        (<FlatList
                            style={styles.feed}
                            data={UserArray}
                            keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderPost(item)}
                            // keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                        ></FlatList>) :
                        (
                 <View style={{  width: '70%', alignSelf: 'center',justifyContent: 'center' , alignItems: 'center', marginTop: '20%'}}>
                    <Feather name="smile" color="#009387" size={40}/>
                    <Text style={{paddingTop: 20, textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#A9A9A9'}}>Hey folk, You dont' have any friends list</Text>
                </View>
                        )
                    }

                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

In my screen i am always getting. You don't have any data.

But in `componentDidMount()` after i fetch data from firestore. Inside my then :

```
.then(doc => {
alert(UserArray.length);
})
```

Its showing correct array count. Here is my friends array :

```
{
  "name": "quaroe",
"number": "3940904",
friends: [
     {
       "name": "alber"
     },
     {
       "name": "romea"
     },
     {
       "name": "basea"
     }
]
}
```

my doubt is that `render` is called before `componentDidMount`. But i tried `componentWillMount`. And i added alert. Always `render` called first and then only `componentWillMount or componentDidMount` is getting called

Comment: `componentWillMount` gets called before `render` and then `componentDidMount` gets called. Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Comment: but i added alert in both. For me render gets called first and then componentWillMount alert coming as second. Why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your UseArray in the state instead. I believe the flatlist is not showing anything because when it is rendered your firebase function is not yet completed so UseArray is empty. And render cant detect changes of your constant UseArray that why it's not showing any list even if your fetch is succesful.

**try this**

```
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userArray: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .doc(`User/${'beQVEcfLsXV8JhA8L2SDDq03bmD3'}`)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        this.setState({userArray: doc.data().friends});
      });
  }

  renderPost = post => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.feedItem}>
        <Feather name="book" style={styles.avatar} size={30} />
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{post.name}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.timestamp}>
                {post.name} | {post.name}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Feather
          name="chevron-right"
          style={{color: '#808080', alignSelf: 'center'}}
          size={20}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.userArray && this.state.userArray.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            style={styles.feed}
            data={this.state.userArray}
            keyExtractor={index => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => this.renderPost(item)}
            // keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          />
        ) : (
          <View
            style={{
              width: '70%',
              alignSelf: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              marginTop: '20%',
            }}>
            <Feather name="smile" color="#009387" size={40} />
            <Text
              style={{
                paddingTop: 20,
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#A9A9A9',
              }}>
              Hey folk, You dont' have any friends list
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give with some example. I am vet new to this react native...It would be helpful to understand more..

Comment: i've updated my answer, please check. hope that would help

Comment: Again my data is not showing. Even i added alert to check. First render called and componentWillMount alert called

Comment: The UserArray outside your class component is not needed cause you will be using the state. In your flatlist data use this `this.state.userArray`. I will try to edit your code and update my answer.